# Where does the return in main() return to?

Tags: java, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who calls the main function in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949642/who-calls-the-main-function-in-java)

Consider this code:

```
class abc {
  public static void main(String x[]) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Where does control go to when `return` is reached? When we execute this program, say via

```
$ java abc
```

the compiler searches for the `main` method and then proceeds further. In other cases, we call a function, and if we reach a `return`, control is returned to the last calling point.

Comment: It ends the main thread.

Comment: As usual, the control goes to wherever it came from :)

Comment: this shouldn't be voted down. this is a valid question about control flow in java.

Comment: @mfrankli Does it show signs of own research effort?

Comment: sorry for this below below below average question, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The control is always returned to the call originator. In this case, the originator could be the operating environment, or another method that called `main` (remember, when it comes to being called, `main` is not special in any way; other methods can call it too).

Comment: +1 For "main is not special in any way"... remembers me how students surprised when some code "calling main" :-)

Comment: i have a viva 2moro and all these stupid questions are originating in my head.. what if my teacher ask me that what do you mean by main thread ends.. or should i just answer that the "program ends after control comes out of main method"

Comment: @rd4code: The program may not end - you may have other foreground threads executing. Just because `main` finishes doesn't mean the JVM dies.

Comment: @rd4code If `main` starts other threads, your program may not end when its main thread finishes.